# My function returns a new line with 'None'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, error-handling

This is my code:

```
def pomo_code_apply():
    if success_name==1:
        print(" "*79,'-$3.00')
    if success_name==3:
        print(" "*78, '-$10.00')
    if success_name==2:
        print(" "*79, '-$7.00')
    else:
        print()
```

and this is to call the function

```
        if success==1:
            print('   Promotion Code',pomo_code_apply())
```

however for my output , im getting this(for this eg let success_name==1)

```
                                                                               -$3.00

   Promotion Code None
```

however i want it like:

```
Promotion Code                                                             -$3.00
```

I do not know why there is a new line for the -3 and why `pomo_code_apply()` returns both none and -3

Comment: Change the `print` statements in `pomo_code_apply` to `return` statements

Comment: Wouldn't you want to pas `success_name` in to the `pomo_code_apply()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

#### Code:

```
success_name = 1
def pomo_code_apply(success_name):
    if success_name==1:
        a =  " "*79 + '-$3.00'
        return a
    if success_name==3:
        a = " "*78 + '-$10.00'
        return a
    if success_name==2:
        a = " "*79 + '-$7.00'
        return a
    else:
        return

print('Promotion Code {}'.format(pomo_code_apply(success_name)))
```

#### Output:

```
Promotion Code                                                                                -$3.00
```

Answer (score 1):

All functions return *something*. If you don't specify what to return, it defaults to `None`.
You are printing whatever `promo_code_apply()` returns, and since you're not specifying what it returns, it prints `None`.
So your options are to either take the promo_code_apply() out out of the print() call like so:

```py
if success == 1:
        print('   Promotion Code', end='')
        pomo_code_apply()
```

Or specify what pomo_code_apply() returns like so:

```py
def promo_code_apply():
    if success_name==1:
        return "{}-$3.00".format(" "*79)
    if success_name==2:
        return "{}-$7.00".format(" "*79)
    if success_name==3:
        return "{}-$10.00".format(" "*79)
    else:
        return ""
```

But if you're going that rout, you might want to take the formatting out of `promo_code_apply()` and put it in later:

```py
def pomo_code_apply():
    if success_name==1:
        return "-$3.00"
    if success_name==2:
        return "-$7.00"
    if success_name==3:
        return "-$10.00"
    else:
        return ""

if success == 1:
        print("   Promotion Code {}{}".format(" "*79, promo_code_apply()))
```